# Неправильно работает qsort

Tags: c, qsort

Мне нужно отсортировать динамический массив строк по сумме количества букв в первом и последнем словах при помощи qsort. Если в компаратор подавать просто строки, то он получает и обрабатывает все правильно, но если его использовать через qsort, то на вход он получает или обрезанные строки из массива или склеенные, следовательно работает неправильно. Что не так с компаратором или функцией qsort. Функция `readAndProcess` работает правильно.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int readAndProcess(int *numberOfStr, char ***text);

int comp ( const void *x, const void *y);

int main (){
    int numberOfStr = 0 ;
    char **text;
    int i = 0;

    readAndProcess(&numberOfStr, &text);
    qsort(*text,numberOfStr,sizeof(char*),comp);

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfStr; i++)
        printf("%s\n",text[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfStr; i++)
        free(text[i]);
    free(text);

return 0;
}

int readAndProcess(int *numberOfStr, char ***text){

    *text = 0;
    char c;
    char* str = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int numOfStr = 0;
    int lenStr = 0;
    int freeStr = 0;

    do{
        c = getchar();

        if (c != EOF){
            str = realloc(str,++lenStr*sizeof(char)+1);
            str[lenStr - 1] = c;
        }

        if (c == '.' || c =='\n' || c == EOF){
            freeStr = 1;
            if (lenStr > 1){
                str[lenStr] = '\0';
                i = 0;
                while (i < numOfStr) 
                    if (strcasecmp(str, (*text)[i++]) == 0)
                        break;

                if(i == numOfStr){
                *text = realloc(*text,++numOfStr*sizeof(char*));
                (*text)[numOfStr - 1] = str;
                str = 0;
                freeStr = 0;
                }

            }
            lenStr = 0;
        }
    }while(c != '\n' && c!= EOF); 

    if (freeStr)
        free(str);
    *numberOfStr = numOfStr;

    return 0;
}

int comp (const void *a, const void *b){

    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int j = 0;
   // printf("1.%s 2.%s\n",a,b);

    j = (((char*)a)[0] == ' ') ? 1 : 0;
    for (j;((((char*)a)[j] != ' ') && (((char*)a)[j] != ',')); j++)
        c++;
    for (j = strlen(((char*)a))-2;(((char*)a)[j] != ' '); j--)
        c++;
    if (c > strlen(((char*)a)))
        c = strlen(((char*)a))-2;

    j = (((char*)b)[0] == ' ') ? 1 : 0;
    for (j;((((char*)b)[j] != ' ') && (((char*)b)[j] != ',')); j++)
        d++;
    for (j = strlen(((char*)b))-2;(((char*)b)[j] != ' '); j--)
        d++;
    if (d > strlen(((char*)b)))
        d = strlen(((char*)b))-2;
   // printf("1.%d 2.%d\n",c,d);
    if(c > d)
        return 1;
    if (c < d)
        return -1;
    if (c == d)
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: qsort работает правильно. Ошибка в чем-то другом )

Comment: но именно из qsort в компаратор подаются странные строки

Comment: @AlexanderChernin поддерживаю. От себя добавлю, что либо вы 1)сортируете строки с константной длинной, например ставите `str[lenStr] = '\0';` сюда выравнивание по границам 128 или 256 символов, либо 2)создаёте массив указателей на строки, и сортируете не `comp(char*,char*)` как сейчас, а `comp(char**,char**)` новый массив

Comment: @Alexander Chernin: Это, разумеется, правильно. Массив состоит из элементов `char *`. Потому и должно быть `sizeof (char *)`.

Comment: @AnT да, согласен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, если я правильно понимаю, что вы пытаетесь сделать, то вызов `qsort` должен выглядеть так

```
qsort(text, numberOfStr, sizeof(char*), comp);
```

А еще лучше

```
qsort(text, numberOfStr, sizeof *text, comp);
```

Никакой `*` перед `text` быть не должно.

Во-вторых, вы сортируете массив из `char *`. Поэтому в ваш компаратор будут приходить указатели `const void *`, которые на самом деле являются `char *const *`. Именно так их и надо интерпретировать.

Вы же их интерпретируете как `char *`. Получается ерунда и "странные строки".

Прекратите этот дикий ад с постоянным повторением `(char*)b`. Начните свой компаратор с получения правильных указателей

```
int comp (const void *a, const void *b) 
{
  const char 
    *str_a = *(const char *const *) a, 
    *str_b = *(const char *const *) b;
  ...
```

и далее уже работайте с `str_a` и `str_b`.